# Auto scroll down a TextArea

Tags: java, scroll, javafx, textarea

I have a `TextArea` that **doesn't scroll down when I add text** in it. I thought using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17799160/javafx-textarea-and-autoscroll), but my `TextArea` is connected to a `StringProperty` like this :

```
consoleTextArea.textProperty().bind(textRecu);
```

So the answer doesn't work for me, *is there another way* to make my `TextArea` scroll down **every time I update it** by the binding?

Comment: you probably can add listener to the textRecu StringProperty.

Comment: Well no, I said it in my post, the listener is not called when there's a change because of the bind I think ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is fast demo of what i meant in comment about adding listener to the textRecu. Yep consoleTextArea.textProperty() can't be changed because of a binding. But textRecu has no binding => can be changed and we can add listener to it.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {
    private StringProperty textRecu = new SimpleStringProperty();
    private TextArea consoleTextArea = new TextArea();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        VBox root = new VBox();

        Button button = new Button("Add some text");
        button.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                //here you change textRecu and not consoleTextArea.textProperty()
                textRecu.setValue(textRecu.getValue() +"New Line\n");
            }
        });

        root.getChildren().addAll(consoleTextArea, button);
        consoleTextArea.textProperty().bind(textRecu);

        //here you also add listener to the textRecu 
        textRecu.addListener(new ChangeListener<Object>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<?> observable, Object oldValue,
                                Object newValue) {
                // from stackoverflow.com/a/30264399/1032167
                // for some reason setScrollTop will not scroll properly
                //consoleTextArea.setScrollTop(Double.MAX_VALUE);
                  consoleTextArea.selectPositionCaret(consoleTextArea.getLength()); 
                  consoleTextArea.deselect(); 
            }
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image][image]

Comment: I have a small bug but I don't now if it's linked, it doesn't go to the end of the textarea, but to end-1 line

Comment: My bug comes from the fact the bind update my String before my textarea

Comment: @EvansBelloeil i think it is some kind of refresh bug in TextArea setText(), but i can be wrong.This post is quite a solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30264399/1032167  Just add  `consoleTextArea.selectPositionCaret(consoleTextArea.getLength());
                consoleTextArea.deselect();` instead of   `consoleTextArea.setScrollTop(Double.MAX_VALUE);`

Comment: Yes, it was it, can you update your post, and explain the bug ?