# How to control the JavaFX TextArea auto scroll?

Tags: java, javafx, textarea, javafx-2, javafx-8

In my application  I am appending the text to `TextArea` every 2 minutes. When ever I append new line to `TextArea` the auto scroll automatically going to down. But I want to stay the scroll where i am keep the scroll button. How to do it in JavaFX.

```
logTextArea.appendText("Here i am appending text to text area"+"\n");
logTextArea.setScrollTop(Double.MIN_VALUE);
```

I tried this but scroll automatically going to down , but I need to keep my scroll chosen position I don't want to go automatically down.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

The most straightforward way is to remember the position of the caret and restore it after it gets moved by `appendText` or `setText`.

Here's how you can do it:

```
int caretPosition = area.caretPositionProperty().get();
area.appendText("Here i am appending text to text area"+"\n");
area.positionCaret(caretPosition);
```

Comment: This worked when being used in a loop to appendText.

Comment: Wouldnt use this even better: 
```
            int caretPosition = getCaretPosition();
            int anchorPosition = getAnchor();
            super.appendText(text);
            selectRange(anchorPosition, caretPosition);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own function to append text. In this method you can use [`setText`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#setText-java.lang.String-), rather than [`appendText`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextInputControl.html#appendText-java.lang.String-) as `appendText` automatically scrolls to the end of the content (`setText` scrolls to the beginning but this can be supressed by setting back the [`scrollTopProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextArea.html#scrollTopProperty--) to its previous value).

**Example**

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);

            TextArea ta = new TextArea();
            root.setCenter(ta);
            Button button = new Button("Append");
            button.setOnAction(e -> {
                appendTextToTextArea(ta, "BlaBlaBla\n");
            });
            root.setBottom(button);

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }


    /**
     * Appends text to the end of the specified TextArea without moving the scrollbar.
     * @param ta TextArea to be used for operation.
     * @param text Text to append.
     */
    public static void appendTextToTextArea(TextArea ta, String text) {
        double scrollTop = ta.getScrollTop();
        ta.setText(ta.getText() + text);
        ta.setScrollTop(scrollTop);
    }
}
```

**Note:**

Alternatively you can also extend `TextArea` and overload `appendText` to be able to specify whether you want to move the scrollbar:

```
public class AppendableTextArea extends TextArea {

    public void appendText(String text, Boolean moveScrollBar) {
        if (moveScrollBar)
            this.appendText(text);
        else {
            double scrollTop = getScrollTop();
            setText(getText() + text);
            setScrollTop(scrollTop);
        }
    }
}
```

and the usage:

```
AppendableTextArea ta = new AppendableTextArea();
ta.appendText("BlaBlaBla\n", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could just add a changeListener to the TextArea which does nothing, or it just scrolls to the top of the TextArea everytime the text inside it is changed.

```
logTextArea.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Object>() {
  @Override
  public void changed(ObservableValue<?> observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
      logTextArea.setScrollTop(Double.MIN_VALUE); //this will scroll to the top
  }
});
```

Now when you `logTextArea.appendText("Here i am appending text to text area"+"\n");` to the TextArea, it should stay at the top.

The idea is taken from: [JavaFX TextArea and autoscroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17799160/javafx-textarea-and-autoscroll)

Comment: where i need to add this one ? means in which class controller class or Application extended class @ user2882590

Comment: You have a controller class, where you declared your TextArea. If I remember correctly, in the `public void initialize()` function you can add this listener to the `logTextArea` if it comes from an fxml file. If not, then you could just add this listener after you create it. so after: `TextArea logTextArea = new TextArea();`

Comment: Ok, But my question is after adding some text to text area i am scroll my button to middle ,after that when i add text the scroll button will not go up side it need to stay back in middle only i want like that. how can i do ?