# TextArea’s ScrollBar’s step size

Tags: javafx

## Problem

By default, as I’m sure most of you are aware of, the step size for the `TextArea` isn’t too great. Is there a way in which you can change it into something greater—make it scroll faster, jump bigger steps per scroll?

### What I’ve tried so far

#### API

I’ve looked through the [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TextArea.html) for the `TextArea`, but can’t seem to find something that would allow me to manipulate the speed of the `TextArea`’s scroll bar.

#### Stackoverflow

Reading up *Stackoverflow*, I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17799160/javafx-textarea-and-autoscroll), but using the code from that article’s top answer—I couldn’t get it to work even in the way that they suggested it would.

### Moreover

It appears to me there’s no way of manipulating the speed of the `ScrollBar` attached to the `TextArea`, but I could truly be wrong.

Perhaps someone could point me in the right direction should there be a way in which you can speed the scroll bar up a little.

Answer (score -1):

This worked for my application despite the janky-ness of it. I'm sure it can be improved upon. Also a good technique for disabling scrolling altogether with javascript.

This function slows down the scroll speed / step size by manually setting the scroll top value based on a variable I have saved on the DOM element itself and I update the variable a set amount each call and then force the element to be scrolled there, overriding the browsers default scroll amount.

```
function elementScrolled(e) {
  // Ensure we have set a default scroll position for the element
  e.target.scrollPos = e.target.scrollPos || 0;

  // Determine if the user is scrolling up or down
  if (e.target.scrollTop > e.target.scrollPos) {
    // On each call of the function, only increment the scroll value by 1.
    e.target.scrollPos += 1
    e.target.scrollTop = e.target.scrollPos
  } 
  else if (e.target.scrollTop < e.target.scrollPos) {
    // On each call of the function, only decrement the scroll value by 1.
    e.target.scrollPos -= 1
    e.target.scrollTop = e.target.scrollPos
  }
}
```