# JavaFX ScrollPane - Scroll down on update

Tags: java, javafx

I have made a `ScrollPane` which contains a `TextArea`. When the `TextArea` gets additional text with the `push()` method, the scroll bar needs to be set to the bottom. However, when `push()` is used, the bar sets to the top instead. I am not sure what methods are needed to set it to the bottom.

Here is the `ScrollPane` code:

```
package Games.UI.RPG;

import Games.Other.Constants;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.input.ScrollEvent;

/**
 * Scrollable window which contains Text messages.
 */
class LogPane extends ScrollPane{

  private TextArea log;

  LogPane(){
    initialize();
  }

  private void initialize(){
    log = new TextArea();
    log.setEditable(false);
    log.prefWidth(512);
    log.setText("Text Log loaded. Messages:");

    setContent(log);
    setFitToWidth(true);
    setFitToHeight(true);

    setMinHeight(Constants.height);
    setMaxHeight(Constants.height);
    setMinWidth(Constants.width / 3);
    setMaxWidth(Constants.width / 3);
  }

  public void push(String message){
    log.setText(log.getText() + "\n" + message);
    setVvalue(getVmax());
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the extra scroll pane? `TextArea` already has a built in scroll bar with this behavior.

Comment: You can bind the `ScrollPane` vvalue property with the `heightProperty` of the `TextArea`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As user1803551 pointed out, you are using a `ScrollPane` and a `TextArea`. `TextArea` has a scroll when it's text get long. So you need to move the `TextArea` scroll to the bottom because the `ScrollPane's` scroll is never shown.

```
public void push(String message)
{
    log.setText(log.getText() + "\n" + message);
    log.selectPositionCaret(log.getLength());
    log.deselect();
}
```

Other ways of moving the `TextArea` scroll to bottom [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17799160/javafx-textarea-and-autoscroll). I personally prefer `log.appendText();`.

Comment: I have changed the Pane type and implemented a fix. Thanks a lot!